# Finding determinant of matrix error

Tags: python, matrix

I keep running into this error and i can't figure what's wrong.

```
 line 81, in determinant
    determinant += newMatrix[0][x] * (-1)**(2+x) * determinant(reduce_matrix(newMatrix,1,x+1))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here is the code for the two functions:

```
def reduce_matrix(M, i, j):
    newMatrix= [[x for x in y] for y in M]
    try:
        for k in range(len(newMatrix)):
            del(newMatrix[k][j-1])
        newMatrix.remove(newMatrix[i-1])
        return newMatrix
    except:
        print ("Row or column not in matrix")
        return M
def determinant(M):
    newMatrix= [[x for x in y] for y in M]
    if len(newMatrix) != len((newMatrix)[0]):
        print ("Not a square matrix")
    if (dimension(newMatrix))==(1,1):
        return newMatrix
    else:
        determinant = 0
        for x in range(len(newMatrix)):
            determinant += newMatrix[0][x] * (-1)**(2+x) * determinant(reduce_matrix(newMatrix,1,x+1))
        return determinant
```

Comment: numpy.linalg.det built-in function  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using `determinant` both as the function name and a local variable inside that function. Bad idea, since the local variable `determinant` shadows the function name and you are trying to call the function recursively.

When the Python interprete sees `determinant(reduce_matrix(newMatrix,1,x+1))`, the only non-shadowed `determinant` it knows about is `int` that you created when you assigned `0` to it, hence the somewhat cryptic error message.

Use something else, such as `det`, for the local variable:

```
det = 0
#rest of code, suitably adjusted
```